# Как сделать чтобы селф бот писал при заходе на сервер участнику?

Tags: python, discord

Я пытаюсь сделать чтобы селф бот писал новому участнику на сервере, я попытался реализовать как обычный бот но он не отправляет, здесь код не могу почему-то оставить помогите пожалуйста с кодом!

код:
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
print('На сервер зашёл чел ему отправляется фиш ссылка')
await member.send("ку, вот ссылка: gg")

Comment: Вставь код как текст, мы поправим как надо

Comment: Я не могу оставить код почему-то щас ещё раз попробую

Comment: @client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('На сервер зашёл чел ему отправляется ссылка')
    await member.send("ку, вот ссылка: gg")

Comment: Код вставляется с помощью тройных апострофов перед кодом и после, там где русская ё.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше делать через класс, а не через `client.event`. Но в классе важен порядок функций, можешь посмотреть [тут](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#event-reference) документацию по эвентам.

```py
intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_member_join(self, member: nextcord.Member):
        if guild.system_channel is not None:
            msg = "ку, вот ссылка: gg"
            await guild.system_channel.send(msg)

bot = Bot(command_prefix="!", description="test", intents=intents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(#TOKEN)
```

Comment: Здраствуйте, я как понимаю это для self бота или нет?